# How to get Jenkins to pick up the correct logs for test cases run in parallel

Tags: java, logging, jenkins, maven-surefire-plugin

I've got a REST Assured suite running in parallel on Jenkins. When the suite was running in serial and a test case failed, Jenkins grabbed and displayed the correct/corresponding logs--but after we moved to run test cases in parallel, it started grabbing a section of the logs more or less at random.

How do we get it to show the logs corresponding to that actual test case?

Comment: Is REST Assured the governing framework or is it being orchestrated by JUnit?
Any ant or gradle involved?

Comment: TestNG framework, maven surefire plugin. REST Assured uses whatever SLF4J implementation you have included as a dependency to log, so its logger isn't exposed directly afaik.